# How do i print the value of all properties in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to use  a for in oop to get the value of all the properties but do not know how.
The tutorial i am following gives this example of how i can do it, but i dont understand it.

```
                     for(var x in dog) { console.log(dog[x]); }

                    var nyc = {
                    fullName: "New York City",
                    mayor: "Michael Bloomberg",
                    population: 8000000,
                     boroughs: 5
                     };

                     // write a for-in loop to print the value of nyc's properties
```

Comment: i know with this code for(var x in dog) { console.log(dog[x]); }

Comment: What does your Javascript book say?

Comment: print the value of each property in nyc using for in loop

Comment: It says a lot more than that. You need to learn the language.

Comment: helpful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: You have an example `for..in` that works on an object called `dog`. Your object is called `nyc`. If you copy that loop to where the "write a loop" comment is, what change do you think you need to make to it to work with your object?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use variable name that has some meaning instead of x and y like:

```
for(var property in object){
    console.log(object[property]);
}
```

for your object

```
for(var prop in nyc){
    console.log(nyc[prop]);
}
```

**Updated for ES6+**

```
for(let prop in nyc){
    console.log(nyc[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var property in obj){
     console.log(property + ": " + obj[property]);
}
```

This should do the trick, what this does is loops through the "Properties" of the object and logs the values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner would be:

`Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => key + ":" value)`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `+` before `value`.

the correct line `Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => key + ":" + value)`