# javascript code printing the values of properties in an object?

Tags: javascript

How do i print the values of the properties of this object. At the moment it just prints the property names not the values.

```
                     var nyc = {
                     fullName: "New York City",
                     mayor: "Michael Bloomberg",
                     population: 8000000,
                     boroughs: 5
                     };


                    for(var x in nyc) { console.log(nyc[x]); }
```

Comment: Just do a `console.log(nyc)`?

Comment: That code **does** print the values.

Comment: Your code appears to be working when I test it.

Comment: It looks like you posted a couple of nearly-identical questions earlier today: [the first one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639246/how-do-i-print-the-value-of-all-properties-in-an-object-in-javascript) asks how to print all of the properties in an object, and [the second one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638710/javascript-printing-the-value-of-a-property) also asks how to print all of the properties in an object. The answers to these two questions should give you the information that you need.

Comment: Would you please stop posting the same question over and over?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is acceptable (at least in my opinion)  to post a question that is similar to an earlier one if you have moved on past the original problem and can say something like "I asked X earlier, and was told Y, but now I find that this has led me to related problem Z". But this question is virtually identical to your earlier question. If you need more information about the answers you were given there please post some comments under those answers, or edit that question to provide additional details. The code you've shown here _will_ print property values, not names.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to say:

```
console.log(x + ": " + nyc[x]);
```

to print both the names and values.

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XMwCE/).